# Notify added comments

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

I noticed that when you write answers, you get notified if a answer is posted before you submit your comment.

Shouldn't this feature be implemented for comments as well? It shouldn't be like a pop-up above the screen but localised in the comments div belonging to the question or answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This already exists, though not at the top of the screen. Often when I'm typing a comment or answer, I see a link appear near the comments area that will do exactly this: 'show x more comments'

Comment: odd, i didn't notice that